# CSS Selector Equivalent Of jQuery.find in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, selector

I have a Marionette view that has the following code:

```
onRender: {
   $('#someDiv').find('a').click(function(){
     // some code here
   });
}
```

But I want to refactor to something like this:

```
events: {
  'click [selector here]': 'executeCode'
},

executeCode: function() {
    // some code here
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually the recommended way of binding DOM event handlers in Backbone. Backbone uses jQuery `on` method (*event delegation syntax*) for binding the event handlers behind the scenes.

Please note that the event handlers work for matching descendants of the View's element. If `#someDiv` is not a descendant of the View's element then the event handler won't work.

It should also be noted that `this` in the context of the handler refers to the View object not the target element of the event:

```
events: {
  'click #someDiv a': 'executeCode'
},

executeCode: function(event) {
   // `this` here refers to the View object 
   var clickedElement = event.currentTarget;
   // ...
}
```

The above snippet works like the following snippet:

```
viewObject.$el.on('click', '#someDiv a', viewObject.executeCode.bind(viewObject));
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use a space

```
events: {
  'click #someDiv a': 'executeCode'
},
```

Also, see http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents